# When uninstalling Ansible, do I need to uninstall ansible-core as well?

Tags: ansible

When uninstalling Ansible, do I need to uninstall ansible-core as well? I wanted to make sure I clear all ansible stuff before I can re-install properly.

Also, what does this code mean when I run `ansible --version`? Shouldn't it return something like `ansible not found`

```
➜  ~ ansible --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ansible", line 34, in <module>
    from ansible import context
ImportError: No module named ansible
```

Looking in this folder `/usr/local/bin/` show this screenshot. Do I need to delete those files too?

[image]

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: macOS Big Sur is on my computer

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
sudo apt-get remove ansible
sudo apt-get purge ansible
```

or:

```
pip uninstall ansible
Uninstalling ansible-2.6.5:
  Would remove:
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible-2.6.5-py2.7.egg-info
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/*
    /usr/local/bin/ansible
    /usr/local/bin/ansible-config
    /usr/local/bin/ansible-connection
    /usr/local/bin/ansible-console
    /usr/local/bin/ansible-doc
    /usr/local/bin/ansible-galaxy
    /usr/local/bin/ansible-inventory
    /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
    /usr/local/bin/ansible-pull
    /usr/local/bin/ansible-vault
Proceed (y/n)? y
```

Comment: Yes, it will but what I'm asking about is the ansible -core. When I uninstall ansible, it didn't remove ansible-core. I'm asking if I should do that.

Answer (score 0):

I could not uninstall Ansible. Running `apt-cache policy ansible` indicated that I had an old version (Ansible 2.9.6). I attempted to uninstall using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove ansible
sudo apt-get purge ansible
pip uninstall ansible
```

However, `which ansible` would still return `/home/<user>/.local/bin/ansible` and `ansible --version` would return `ansible [core 2.12.3]`
According to [Ansible - Upgrading from 2.9](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html) "Starting in version 2.10, Ansible is made of two packages. When you upgrade from version 2.9 and older, you need to uninstall the old Ansible version (2.9 or earlier) before upgrading."
In my case, this was accomplished by also running:

```
pip uninstall ansible-base
```